# creating sql tables with 4 many to many

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a .json file which looks like this:

```
{
    "pool1": {
        "machine1": {
            "user1": ["processA"],
            "user2": ["processB","processA"]
        },
        "machine2":{
            "user1": ["processA"]
        }
    },
    "pool2": {
        "machine1": {
            "user1": ["processA"],
            "user2": ["processB","processA"]
        },
        "machine3":{
            "user2": ["processC", "processA"]
            "user3": ["processD", "processB"]
        }
    }
}
```

We have pools, pools have machine (1 machine can be in many pools)
On every machine, there are users (Users Can be on many machines)
Every user run 1 or more processes (a process can be run by different users, on the same machine) 
* A machine that is in 2 or more pool will have the same data inside

I want to build a SQL database from this data in python SQLAlchemy

```
class Pool(Base):
    __tablename__ = "pools"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class Machine(Base):
    __tablename__ = "machines"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class Process(Base):
    __tablename__ = "processes"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    uid = Column(Integer)
    uname = Column(String)
```

My question is how do I create a table which will look like this:

```
|pool_id|machine_id|user_id|process_id|
---------------------------------------
|1      |1         |1      |1
|1      |1         |2      |2
|1      |2         |2      |1
|2      |1         |1      |1
|2      |1         |2      |2
|2      |3         |3      |4
|2      |3         |3      |2
|2      |3         |2      |1
|2      |3         |2      |3
```

Comment: is there a specific RDBMS you are using ? (MSSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL)

Comment: I prefer sqlite3, but anything will go

Answer (score 1):

You don't want just ONE table to handle this, you will likely want many tables to handle these relations.  There are several ways that you can do this but this is my suggestion:

```
|    User   |      |   Machine    |      |   Pools   |       |   Process  |
-------------      ----------------      -------------       --------------
| - user_id |      | - machine_id |      | - pool_id |       | process_id |


|   machine_users   |    |  user_processes |    |   pool_machines   |
---------------------    -------------------    ---------------------
| - machine_id (fk) |    | - user_id (fk)  |    | - pool_id (fk)    |
| - user_id (fk)    |    | - proc_id (fk)  |    | - machine_id (fk) |
```

My logic behind this:

- Having different tables for each entity: more likely that we will adhere to the [the second normal form](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm#label3.1) and [fourth normal form](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm#label4.1)
- Creating relations in separate tables between the entities: [adhere to the third normal form](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm#label3.2), [the fourth normal form](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm#label4.1), and [fifth normal form](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm#label4.1)

Besides ad hereing to the normal form principals in relational design there are some obvious reasons as to why this will function better.

- We decouple the tables, prevent a full outer join or cross product between all the relations.  This will reduce table bloat.
- Since the tables are decoupled, we can easily add new fields later on.
- This will be MUCH easier to update since all the relations are handled by FK/PK defined relations.  If we just want to update the name of the machine with id = 1, we can run one simple query.

Comment: This is probably the best architectural structure for the data from the information we have been given.